# ReactiveX collect elements processed before a failure

Tags: error-handling, rx-java

I'm using RxJava to create a background job syncronizing my db.
It connects to an external source and start to process entries, map them and insert in the db.
When it ends I need the list with all the elements processed, I can get it when everything goes right, but how can I collect all the elements processed if during the flow something fail?

```
final List<String> res = Observable.create(onSubscribe)
        .buffer(4)
        .flatMap(TestRx::doStuff)
        .buffer(8)
        .map(TestRx::calculateList)
        .toList()
        .toBlocking()
        .single();
System.out.println("strings = " + res);
```

What I would like to have is a way that if `doStuff` or `calculateList` throw exceptions, the flow stop an returns the list with everything it processed until the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<String> res = Observable.create(onSubscribe)
    .buffer(4)
    .flatMap(TestRx::doStuff)
    .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty()) // turn error into completion
    .buffer(8)
    .map(TestRx::calculateList)
    .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty()) // turn error into completion
    .toList()
    .toBlocking()
    .single();
System.out.println("strings = " + res);
```

Comment: on error resume continue to execute the flow, I need it to stop on error

Comment: @rascio Original flow stops on error, processing continues with new flow that you provide with `onErrorResumeNext`, which is `empty` flow, i.e. you complete the flow immediately.